# Multiple cover of a rational curve in Fano

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective Fano variety of dimension $n$ with Picard number one.
Let $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to X$ be a rational curve of anticanonical degree $d$.
Let $g: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a degree $m$ map. Then the composition $f \circ g$ will give a degree $md$ rational curve in $X$.

Question: Does $f \circ g$ give a new rational curve in the Hilbert scheme? The image of $f$ and the image of $f \circ g$ are same in $X$.  $f$ and $f \circ g$ are different in $\text{Mor}(\mathbb{P}^1, X)$, but are they different in the Hilbert scheme of rational curves in $X$ ?

Comment: No, definitely it does not give a "new" rational curve in the Hilbert scheme.  The rational transformation from the smooth Deligne-Mumford stack of stable maps to projective space to the Hilbert scheme of projective space is undefined on the locus parameterizing stable maps that contain a multiple cover as a subcurve.  But look at Castravet's "almost nice" component.  This is not the locus of multiple covers (or else it would exist for every genus, not just even genus).